# text moving out of column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to keep the text to move to next line in order to keep it in its own column but my text is overflowing. I want all 1's to stay in 1st col. Any hints on what i might need to change/add?

Heres the code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid ">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4"> Col1  1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">Col2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">Col3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Heres the link to how it looks:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljnftjbp/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.col-sm-4 {
   -moz-hyphens:auto;
   -ms-hyphens:auto;
   -webkit-hyphens:auto;
   hyphens:auto;
   word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

This should do the job. 
Your problem was, that the browser can't decide where to put a break since you don't have a single space. With hyphens you force him to just break to the next line when there's not enough space. Check here for Browser Support: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to use CSS "overflow", perhaps checkout this link which will tell you what it is:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

PS: Checkout the Property Values section for the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

It is **css bootstrap default overflow might be not hidden** so the text flows use the class **col-md-1**
[image: make the col-sm-1 to col-md-1]

[image: Here is the output]